# What does '(Required)' mean exactly in get_survey_details?

Tags: surveymonkey

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_details
says (for example)
data.pages[*].questions[*].answers[_].is_answer
(Required)

What does (Required) mean there? Not all responses contain all (Required) fields so it does not mean that a field thus marked is always returned.

Just wondering,

Patrick

Edit 25-July: I am asking this in the context of an "Other (please specify)" option.
Here is an example

```
{"text": "Annet (vennligst spesifiser)", "visible": true, "is_answer": true, "apply_all_rows": false, "type": "other", "answer_id": "6886575992"}]
```

Can I be sure that the presence of an "is_answer" field means that this is a free text input to a multiple-choice single-response question? Optiontype 10 in the old RDD format. I think optiontype 10 was not counted as a response in Responses.xls while optiontype 11 was in both Responses.xls and ResponsesText.xls but my memory of that is fading. Anyway, that is past now so I just want to be sure I correctly identify this response type.

Answer (score 1):

"required" means that a value will always be returned by the API. Other attributes marked as "optional" will only be returned for certain kinds of data. For example "data.pages[*].questions[*].answers[*].items[*].type" which is marked "optional" will only be returned for matrix question types as described in the description for that attribute to the right.

Comment: The word "always" is what I was wondering about. Maybe 
 "required" means that a value will always be returned by the API IF the value is not null?
In which case it looks the same as "optional" to me.
Or maybe it means: a value is returned IF the user specified that option in the survey setup? Like the 'Make this an answer choice.' for 'Other (please specify)'

BTW is there a way in Stackexchange to make the Enter key give me a newline here rather than having to remember to press Shift+Enter?  Pressing Return means I keep posting  the comment before I have finished. And only 5 mins to edit.